# Paste values disabled in Excel when recording a macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I started to record a macro, added a name and inserted the formula `=NOW( )` in a cell.

After selecting and copying this cell, I want to convert the formula to its value by "Paste Values" in Home->Clipboard->Paste menu.

The Paste Values submenu command is disabled, and the Record Macro button is disabled. This results in being unable to stop recording the macro.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to replicate this behaviour so not sure why you are unable to stop recording your macro but ...

I presume you are trying to have the cell contents contain the time / date at a fixed point and not change every time you open the spreadsheet or recalculate? If so, a line such as:

```
activesheet.range("A1").value = now()
```

This removes the need to faff about with copying and pasting values.

HTH